# converting String to List

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller which pulls a list of students and displays in a view, Below part of my controller action which stores students in a list and then to a TempData Variable. Then I redirect it to a different action to display the list in a view:

```
var StudentsList = (from s in data.vwStudents.Where(a => a.StudentID == Id)
                   group s by s.StudentName into g
                   select g.Key).ToList();

TempData["StudentsList"] = StudentsList;

return RedirectToAction("DisplayStudents");
```

I pass the TempData["StudentList"] variable to another Controller Action:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult DisplayStudents()
    {
        ViewData["StudentsList"] = TempData["StudentsList"];
        return View();
    }
```

Here is how I display students in a view:

```
         <%= ViewData["StudentsList"]%> <br /><br />
```

The issue is, I am not able to see students, Instead I see:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
```

Do I need to convert the TempData to a list before passing it to the view? or do I do it in the view? Also, How do I convert TempData variable to a list?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that `StudentsList.ToString()` == `System.Collections.Generic.List\`1[System.String]`.  What did you expect?

Comment: @mellamokb I was expecting student names listed instead of the type.

Comment: Lists do not have a natural output format because there is no "one obvious way" to display the contents of a list.  Your idea of how to display the contents of a list will be different than the next programmer.  So you have to define it yourself.

Comment: @mellamokb Understood. Thanks! for the Info. Need to read on certain topics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is a list of names, not a single name; if your model were just a string, the engine could dump it onto the page as-is and call it good. But it *doesn't know what to do with a list,* because there's any number of ways to arrange something like that.

It doesn't know what you want: a comma-separated list? A bunch of bullet points? A table? The engine has no idea, so it gives up and asks you for instructions.

**So you need to tell the view how to display your list.** How you do that is up to you, but I'll give you an example. I'm more familiar with the Razor engine, so I'll attempt this in that syntax:

```
<ul>    
    @foreach (string name in (List<string>)ViewData["StudentsList"])
    {        
        <li>@name</li>        
    }    
</ul>
```

That should generate a bulleted list of student names. If you want it in a different format, just use divs or something instead of the ul/li construct.

Answer (score 4):

Use following :

```
string.Join(",",(List<string>)ViewData["StudentsList"])).ToArray());
```